# Some missing icons (no entry sign)

Tags: 22.04, icons

Just installed 22.04 and I have been trying to work out how to create url shortcuts but in my attempts I seem to have lost some icons (well...stop sign) e.g. show applications in favourites bar, gedit in applications, all the screenshot buttons etc. I installed gnome tweaks and then was playing around with usr/share/applications/ . any suggestions to restore them?

Update: Ok, I simply removed gnome-tweak-tool and that restored icons. Now back to how to create shortcuts...

Comment: You can install MenuLibre application. It creates launchers in Gnome.

Comment: Thank you, will try that